# Unable to update protractor config at runtime

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to update protractor config on the run time, because spec file are being read from external excel file.

Below is my config:

```typescript
export let config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: RunConfig.allScriptsTimeout,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: RunConfig.browser
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: RunConfig.baseUrl,
  framework: RunConfig.framework,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: RunConfig.defaultTimeoutInterval,
    print: function () {
    }
  },
  onPrepare() {
    bot.fullScreen();
    Xlsx.readExcel();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  },
  beforeLaunch() {
    let spec =  new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve({
        specs: Xlsx.readSpecs()
      });
    });
  },
  resultJsonOutputFile: RunConfig.resultFile
}
```

According to [this](https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor/blob/c2b40610f5c840d338df4569d30e4cd08bdaa767/spec/beforeLaunchConf.js) it should update config in beforeLaunch

==========================

ReadSpec Function

```
readSpecs() {
   fs.readFile(RunConfig.runManager, (err, buf) => {
      if(!err && buf) {
        let wb = XLSX.read(buf, { type: 'buffer' });
        let sheet = wb.Sheets[sheetNames.specs]; //reading specs
        let specArr = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
        let spec;
        specArr.forEach(element => {
          spec.push(element.spec);
        });
        return spec;
      } else {
        return [];
      }

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add explanation inline:

```
XLSX = require('xlsx');

// change readSpecs() to sync style
readSpecs() {
    let wb = XLSX.readFile(RunConfig.runManager);
    let sheet = wb.Sheets[sheetNames.specs]; //reading specs
    let specArr = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
    let spec;
    specArr.forEach(element => {
        spec.push(element.spec);
    });
    return spec;
}


export let config = {

    // specify value for `specs`, and it require `Xlsx.readSpecs()` 
    // does not return promise-like object.
    specs: Xlsx.readSpecs(),

    onPrepare() {
        bot.fullScreen();
        // you need to move Xlsx.readExcel(); to the top
        // when protractor run into onPrepare() function,
        // it means protractor runner had accepted your passed-in config
        // the runner won't accept any changes to the config once it accepted.
        // Xlsx.readExcel(); 

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
            spec: {
                displayStacktrace: true
            }
        }));
    },

    // beforeLaunch() is unnecessary    
    // beforeLaunch() {
    //     let spec = new Promise((resolve) => {
    //         resolve({
    //             specs: Xlsx.readSpecs()
    //         });
    //     });
    // },
};
```

`beforeLaunch()` can't change the config yet. There is no hooks can change the config before protractor read it. The only way is to give a pre-know value to `specs` and not allow promise-like value.

If your `Xlsx.readExcel()` or `Xlsx.readSpecs()` return promise, you have to use another way to implement it.

[image]

Comment: That will be working if Xlsx.readExcel(); return immediately.
but in this case, I am fetching results from excel and returning. so it take some time and specs are getting undefined at this time.

Comment: readExcel is different function. the function I am using here is readSpec
I have added this in question now.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the local variable `spec` for anything in the `beforeLaunch` function. The example in the link you posted is returning the resolved promise. You need to get rid of the local variable and return the promise like this:

```
beforeLaunch() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({
      specs: Xlsx.readSpecs()
    });
  });
}
```